# Android <--> python sockets

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

I'm using standard java.net.Socket in android and socket module in python, and when i do following in java:

```
sk = new Socket(addr, port);
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
output = new DataOutputStream(sk.getOutputStream());
...
output.writeUTF("connect 216082611046");
String message = input.readLine();
Log.wtf("cst", message);
```

And following in python:

```
...
connection, addr = server.accept()
print "Received connection from", addr  
s = connection.recv(1024)
...
connection.sendall(ip) #ip is some string there
```

i get in trouble: java receives message sent by "connection.sendall(ip)", but only when i close the sockets, but i need to keep it alive and continue messaging based on data received. Is there any way to get answer without closing sockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cause of this behaviour could be that your `ip` string doesn't end with a newline.

`readLine` tries to read a whole line, so if there's no newline coming in on the input stream, it will block until the stream is closed.